# Using two arguments / triggers in an IFTTT recipe

Tags: if-this-then-that

I'd like to use two arguments / triggers in an IFTTT recipe. What I want to do is :

---

**IF** time is 08:00 **AND** weather is <15°

**THEN**

Turn on WeMo switch (which I have connected to the heater in my office, so it's warm in the morning).

---

Is it possible to do this using IFTTT? I can build the recipe using either TIME or WEATHER but can't seem to do both (in a similar way to how you would write `&&` in a PHP 'if' block).

Comment: No, I'm afraid there isn't. (I've been looking for a way to daisy-chain IFTTT triggers myself. Perhaps that's something they could add as a premium feature.)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same limitation and started developing a cloud application which allows you to exactly that. It's basically an extension for IFTTT with the capabilities to store variables and execute some basic logic.
It's not as user-friendly as IFTTT, so it's good if you have a basic understanding of variables and so on.

Check it out at [apilio.io](http://www.apilio.io) and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same, but, you can perhaps set the switch to default on using the WEMO app, then use IFTTT to turn it off if the condition does not exist.  Not as elegant as your solution, but it may work.

Comment: Good work around, ill give it a try, i dreamt up somthing similar by daisy chaining wemos but its more complex and required purchasing more of them

Answer (score 0):

I was directed to try Yahoo Pipes for this task.

Pipes has a much richer filter system that lets you put in multiple words and sites. So, for instance, you can look for "solar" AND "power" on [slashdot,ars]. Then you send the output of the filter to some sort of endpoint, like an RSS feed. Then connect the IFTTT to the RSS, and use that to notify you.

This does seem to solve the problem, but honestly I couldn't get the pipe to work properly and lost interest. Nevertheless the basic idea is sound, so I would recommend giving it a try - and if you get it to work, let us know how!

Comment: Sadly, it looks like Y! Pipes has been shut down.

Comment: Indeed, rather sad. I have not found a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking for the answer to this problem, I found http://polyideas.com/post/137921254979/advanced-scripts-for-iftttcom-and-adafruit-io describes using Adafruit IO, that will provide a channel which you can connect to your local server (Raspberry Pi). If that is too complex, Numerous may provide the functionality you need.

It seems the ittt maker channel could do this too.